# How can I specify selection foreground in VS Code (without high contrast theme)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to specify the text color when highlighting in VS Code using `"editor.selectionForeground"` but that property applies only to high contrast themes.  This issue mentions making that setting apply to all themes:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36490

How exactly would I do that?